# Use Long value as drop and take in a quill query

Tags: database, scala, pagination

I have a simple endpoint which returns some records from a database. The endpoint supports pagination.
Therefor i have the following quill-query

`query[HandbookModule].drop(lift(offset)).take(lift(limit))`

I want to support int64/Long values for the pagination but quill only supports Int values as far as i know.

Did I just miss how to do this or is this not possible with quill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32-bit integer max value is well over 2 billion. Are you sure your database will actually ever have that volume? Maybe narrowing that long to int will do the job?

Anyway, you can customize quill to some extent with infix dsl:

```
def find(..., take: Long, ...) = {
    implicit class LongTake[T](q: Query[T]) {
      def lTake(l: Long) = quote(infix"$q take $l".as[Query[T]])
    }
    query[HandbookModule].drop(lift(offset)).lTake(lift(limit))
}
```